# express-form custom validation

Tags: node.js, express, validation

Using the [Express-form](https://github.com/freewil/express-form) module to validate input. Specifically looking at the [custom methods](https://github.com/freewil/express-form#custom-methods) is it possible to write a validation function whose outcome will depend on another field.

Or rather, what I want to achieve is one field to be required if some value is selected in a drop down, but not required for other values.

As for "what have you tried" comments. I haven't, reading the docs I can't figure out how to start.

Comment: there is the `required()` method of a field, but that is as far as it goes, no you cannot do what you try to accomplish with that module, instead you can try other modules which >allow< more, and not get lost in `.custom()`

Comment: Yes, the `required()` I have in place, this would more be a `required_if()`. Any suggestion on such a module?

Comment: try this https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Answer (score 0):

### Node-Express form validation using express-form

> First install express-form module
>
> command :- ***npm install express-form --save***
>
> Second install express flash
>
> command :- ***npm install express-flash***

### Then

> index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var form = require('express-form');          
var field = form.field;                      
var flash = require('express-flash');        


var port = process.env.PORT || 5000 ;  

app.use(flash()); 

app.get('/registration', function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/registration', {
        messages : req.flash('error')
    });
}); 

app.post('/submit', 

form(
            field("firstname").trim().required(),
            field("lastname").trim().required(),
            field("email").trim().required().isEmail()
    ),

function (req, res) {

    if(!req.form.isValid) 
    {
        req.flash('error', req.form.errors);
        res.redirect('/registration');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Form submitted successfully...")
    }

});

app.listen(port);
```

> Note :-

In above code i am using *'ejs' template engine*

for more help [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-form)